# react-router + nginx ingress refresh causes white screen when path is not "/"

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kubernetes, react-router

So I've been trying to fix this for days now and I'm beyond stuck.

My app is running, and I can access the site when I go to the default url (example.com). I can refresh on this url without issues, and I can navigate through the pages being rendered through react router as long as I don't refresh on any other page. (e.g.) refreshing on example.com/path1 doesn't work, I get a 404 error.

My current ingress file looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myApp-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.app.com
      secretName: myApp-tls
  rules:
    - host: "my.app.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /.*
            backend:
              service:
                name: myApp
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I've added many of the most common replies to issues such as this, but it only makes matters worse, such as white screen with "Unexpected token '<'" errors for all javascript files it tries to load, and none of the pages loading at all.

For example, I've tried:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

I've tried adding additional paths to the controller for each route available in the app, I've tried setting the path to just "/" or "/(.*)", nothing is working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you!

EDIT:

```
# latest active node image
FROM node:14-alpine

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
COPY tsconfig.json /app
COPY webpack.config.js /app
COPY .env.prod .env
ADD src /app/src
ADD dist /app/dist
RUN mkdir -p /app/dist/js && chown -R node:node /app/dist/js

ADD server /app/server
ADD assets /app/assets
ADD config /app/config

ARG NPM_TOKEN
COPY .npmrc_docker .npmrc
RUN npm cache verify
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:prod
RUN rm -f .npmrc

# Expose necessary port
EXPOSE 3000

# Compile typescript and start app
CMD ["cross-env", "NODE_ENV=production", "PORT=3000", "ts-node", "server/server"]
```

I've also tried doing it with `CMD ["npx", "http-server", "./dist", "-p", "3000"]` since the server part is only doing the following:

```
      this.app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist")));
      this.app.get("*", (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
        response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist/index.html"));
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I found the real problem.

My domain uses both DigitalOcean and Microsoft name servers. I had the A record added on DO, but I guess it needs to be on both. So I added the A record to the other and now my config in my question works perfectly.

Comment: Is there any way for this to run locally? I am running my app locally with self signed certificates on ingress I am facing same issues

Answer (score 2):

Your `path: /.*` has no capture groups, so `/$1` and `/$2` are undefined.

Try the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myApp-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.app.com
      secretName: myApp-tls
  rules:
    - host: "my.app.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /(.*)
            backend:
              service:
                name: myApp
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: This still gives a 404 after refreshing any page other than the "/" page.

Comment: You'll need `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html` as well.

Comment: Adding that causes all the js files to have the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile? Are you also using react-scripts to build your app?

Comment: Added dockerfile, just to note, I am able to run the docker image locally without any issues

Comment: Edited my answer, I misunderstood and thought you were serving your build assets via nginx as well. Are you certain you even need the rewrite rule?

Comment: Also, `Unexpected token '<'` leads me to believe a syntax error was introduced during minification of your typescript files. Have you just successfully built the container locally, or have you also run it locally?

Comment: No, I am not sure it need the rewrite, right now and in my current ingress config, I'm not using any rewrites, I gave that as an example for some of the different annotations I've added to try to resolve this.

I'm able to run it. The app runs on nginx as well, I just can't refresh. With my current config, I get a 404, when I change to something like what you gave, it gives the unexpected token error.

It seems to me that this is caused by it trying to rewrite the javascript as the html file? I don't really know enough about how it works and I'm pretty new to this, so I may be off on that

Comment: It kind of seems like when I do what you have in your answer, it's serving the index.html file for the given route, but when it tries to get the javascript files to actually do something, maybe it's looking to index.html as well?

Comment: You could confirm that with the network tab in your browser, look at what the response body contains.

Comment: It's loading the files successfully, but the response for all of them is the same as the index.html file, which is why it seems to me that it's replacing the js files with the index.html due to the try_files or something.

Comment: So it's like it needs to know to replace all the paths other than the one's that are .js files with index.html

Comment: using this makes everything 404 for me including /

Answer (score 2):

So I think I found the issue, it seems to be working now, I still run into a problem of cmd shift r occasionally giving an unexpected token, but as a whole it seems to work.

I added the run script to the package.json, and I'm using that as the CMD now

`CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]`

I also moved the javascript from the webpack build back to the root of the dist directory.

I don't really understand why it works now, and if I find anymore information on it, I'll update it here.

Edit:

It turns out this didn't work, I think at some point the app was cached and it just seemed like it was working, still stuck and hoping to find a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved configuring your static content deployment image with next Nginx config:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            internal;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            internal;
        }
    }
}
```

special atenttion on try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; it do the job

your docker file can look as follows

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine3.17
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```